# Npgsql namespace not found after installing with Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I'm using .net6.0 for a backend and I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server. I've run the command `dotnet add package Npgsql` and then `dotnet restore`, but I still get the following error when I try to import and use any of the packages:

```
The type or namespace name 'Npgsql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

For example, the error occurs on the line:

```
using Npgsql;
```

and the line:

```
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? The [installation guide](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html) seems to indicate I can simply install the package via NuGet. Thanks in advance!

I tried running the command `dotnet add package Npgsql` and `dotnet restore`. When I run `dotnet list package`, the package is listed there. It's also present in the `.csproj` file with the line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="7.0.1" />
```

Comment: try clean build, reopening the visual studio

Comment: Which .net version are you using? most likely you are trying to install latest package on the .net version which is not supported by that package. Make sure that package major vesion correspond to .net version.
If it is not the case, please provde the `dotnet restore` outputs. Most likely there is some error.

Comment: Thanks! I have restarted VS Code and run `dotnet build` but that does not solve the problem. Here is the [output](https://pastebin.com/raw/Cetzwv0F) of `dotnet restore`. I'm using .net 6.0 and the Npgsql package says it is [valid with 5.0 or above](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was installing the package in a subdirectory rather than in the parent directory, so my file couldn't access the package's namespace. I solved this by installing the package in the main project directory.